# Why does mktime() need to know about daylight saving time?

Tags: c, datetime

So `mktime()` returns a `time_t` value which is defined as "an integral value representing the number of seconds elapsed since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC" ([source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/)). I can convert a date to a `time_t` value by using `mktime()`. For example, to convert the date 10-Sep-2017 08:34:56 to a `time_t` I'd do the following:

```
struct tm tm;
time_t tv;

tm.tm_sec = 56;
tm.tm_min = 34;
tm.tm_hour = 8;
tm.tm_mday = 10;
tm.tm_mon = 8;
tm.tm_year = 117;
tm.tm_isdst = ????;

tv = mktime(&tm);
```

Now what I don't understand is the idea behind the `tm_isdst` parameter: It is described as "a flag that indicates whether daylight saving time is in effect **at the time described**" ([source](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime)).

This description is somewhat confusing me because I'm of the opinion that the time I'm describing in `struct tm` is in fact already a UTC time and the `time_t` value I want to have from `mktime()` is UTC as well. But UTC time doesn't change with a change of seasons, so why does `mktime()` need to bother with daylight saving time at all? Isn't the advantage of using UTC instead of local time that I won't have to bother with daylight saving time? So why do I have to set `tm_isdst` then?

I'm sure the answer is really simple but at the moment I'm failing to see it. Could somebody please provide a simple example that illustrates why `mktime()` needs the `tm_isdst` parameter to convert a certain date and time to a `time_t` value?

Comment: The very same [manual for mktime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) that you linked, tells you: _The mktime() function converts a broken-down time structure, **expressed as local time**, to calendar time representation._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether DST is in effect changes what the epoch time will be because `mktime` uses the current time zone to determine the time.

For example, if I populate `tm` with 1/1/70 00:00:00 as follows:

```
tm.tm_sec = 0;
tm.tm_min = 0;
tm.tm_hour = 0;
tm.tm_mday = 1;
tm.tm_mon = 0;
tm.tm_year = 70;
tm.tm_isdst = 0;
```

I get a value of 18000 for `tv` because my timezone is GMT-5 (18000 = 3600 * 5).  If I change the value of `tm_isdst` to 1, then `tv` will be set to 14400 (3600 * 4).

Setting `tm_isdst` to -1 will look at the local timezone database to see if DST is in effect for the given date/time.

Comment: Also note that there's one hour (assuming 1hr DST offset) per year during which a time with `tm_isdst==-1` is ambiguous.

Comment: OT portability concern: as `struct tm` may have additional members than the specified 9, code like `struct tm tm = { 0 };` insures all members are initialized/assigned prior to the `mktime(&tm)`.

Answer (score 2):

> Now what I don't understand is the idea behind the `tm_isdst` parameter:
>   It is described as "a flag that indicates whether daylight saving time
>   is in effect at the time described" (source).
>
> This description is somewhat confusing me because I'm of the opinion
>   that the time I'm describing in `struct tm` is in fact already a UTC
>   time

Well, that's your main problem.  Per its documentation, which you already linked, `mktime()` converts a time structure *expressed as local time* to a `time_t`.

> and the time_t value I want to have from mktime() is UTC as well.

Again according to the docs, when a `time_t` is interpreted as an absolute time, it represents the number of seconds elapsed since the Epoch, **in UTC**, so that's indeed what you will get from `mktime()`.  But that means that there is, in general, a time zone and possibly daylight-saving difference between the two representations.

The C library relies on contextual localization data for the time zone applicable to local time, but although it knows the current rules for daylight saving time, it does not necessarily know the rules that were in effect at the specified time.  Moreover, there are edge cases at the changeovers between daylight time and standard time.  For these and perhaps other reasons, you need to tell `mktime()` whether the time given refers to daylight saving time or standard time.

> But UTC time doesn't change with a change of seasons, so why does
>   mktime() need to bother with daylight saving time at all?

Because `mktime()` accepts local time as input.

> Isn't the
>   advantage of using UTC instead of local time that I won't have to
>   bother with daylight saving time?

That is one of the advantages, yes.

> So why do I have to set tm_isdst
>   then?

Because `mktime()` accepts local time as input.

Answer (score 0):

`struct tm` can be thought of as a [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp).

Example: When a timezone goes from daylight time to standard time, the "day" has 25 hours and `struct tm` needs more info than just "Y-M-D h:m:s".

The local time may be 2:30 AM daylight time and then 1 hour later it is 2:30 AM standard time.  `.tm_isdst` is especially useful to distinguish that case.  Note that `.tm_isdst` is relevant in all timestamps.

As `struct tm` itself *does not contain the timezone* (that info exist elsewhere), `.tm_isdst` is designed to provide time stamps indication of  standard time or daylight time (or even unknown standard/daylight).

If the `.tm_isdst` is set to `-1` (unknown)  and the timezone is UTC, then the expectation is that, for all timestamps, it is as if `.tm_isdst == 0`.